# angularjs ng-show not working when first displaying page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some HTML in all my partials

```
<div class="alert alert-info" style="padding:50px" data-ng-show="!doneLoading">Loading Page data .....</div>
```

In my Controller, I have some JavaScript to initialize the 'doneLoading'.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

function MainController($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.doneLoading = false;
    $scope.hasPageLoadError = false;
    $scope.pageLoadErrorMsg = "";

    console.log("getting main");

    $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
        $location.hash(id);
        //console.log($location.hash());
        $anchorScroll();
    };

    $scope.doneLoading = true;
}

myApp.controller("MainController", MainController);
```

})();

When I first load the page in the browser, the 'Loading Page data .....' displays.  If I navigate to any other partial and come back to the original page, it goes away as expected.

Why does the initial load not work properly?

Comment: Are you wrapping your `doneLoading` logic in promises? Can you show a bit more of that?

Comment: right now the controller does not load any data.  I have this code for future use.  I have added the entire controller in my question

Comment: Based on what you are saying it should obviously work. You are missing some piece of information that is causing this to break.

Comment: `data-ng-show = "!doneLoading"`.  You are showing the form if it is __not__ done loading?

Comment: Correct ryanyuyu.  I want it to display the "Loading Page data ....." when doneLoading is false.  I have my page content in another <div style="padding:50px" data-ng-show="doneLoading">.  So I have a div with data-ng-show="!doneLoading" and another with data-ng-show="doneLoading" .  So only one should show.  But they are both showing on the first load.

Comment: @DavidChampion Are you sure there is no missing information present? Feel free to browse the fiddle I threw together as it displays the done loaded as we should expect. http://jsfiddle.net/wgssyr8f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another error in the console when the page was loading that in had been ignoring because I did not think it was related.  Once I corrected that error things began to work

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show "loading data" first then display "done" once it finishes?

you can try to use $timeout in your controller as this:

```
function alertCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.loading = true;
console.log("getting main");
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.loading = false;
},1000);};
```

Then your template looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="alertCtrl" class="alert alert-info" style="padding:50px">
<span data-ng-show="loading">Loading Page data .....</span> 
<span data-ng-show="!loading">Done</span>
```

Make sure you inject $timeout in your controller.